# Kill a script containing `time.sleep()`

Tags: python, sleep, kill

I take notes in class on my computer and share these notes via a public folder on dropbox. When I take notes in class, I create a lot of unnecessary files (I take notes in LaTeX) before I generate a PDF. I don't want to clutter my dropbox space with the unnecessary files, and would rather post only the PDFs to dropbox.

In order to facilitate all of this, I set up a cronjob that runs a python script (below) after every class (weekly). Sometimes, I stay back for a few minutes while I fix something in my notes before I export a PDF, so the python script has a bunch of `sleep`s in it, waiting for the PDF to be generated. I accidentally manually ran that script today, and need help stopping it.

```
import os
import subprocess

from sys import exit as crash
from datetime import date as dt
from time import sleep

def getToday():
 answer = dt.strftime(dt.today(), "%b") + str(int(dt.strftime(dt.today(), "%d")))
 return answer

def zipNotes(date):
 today = getToday()
 while 1:
  if today not in os.listdir('.'):
   with open("FuzzyLog", 'a') as logfile:
    logfile.write("Sleeping\n")
   sleep(60*5) # sleep 5 minutes
   continue
  if "Notes.pdf" not in os.listdir(today):
   with open("FuzzyLog", 'a') as logfile:
    logfile.write("pdf not exported. Sleeping\n")
   sleep(60*5) # sleep 5 minutes
   continue

  subprocess.call("""zip Notes.zip */Notes.pdf""", shell=True)
  crash(0)

zipNotes(getToday())
```

Since the script doesn't find any files made today (I could easily just create a dummy file, but that's not a "proper" solution), it loops through the sleep condition infinitely. Since the looping conditions are quite simple, I can't count on the process to be active for very long to "catch it in the act" to get its PID to kill it.

`ps aux | grep python` doesn't show me which PID is running the python script I want to kill, nor does `ps -ax | grep python` or `ps -e | grep python`.

Does anyone have any idea how I can track a python script while it's sleeping?
I'm on Mac OSX 10.7.5 (Lion), if that matters

Comment: If you're going to update the script to make it easier to find and kill, why not update it to make it possible to shut down cleanly instead?

Comment: @abarnert: I /could/ update the script (how?), but for now, I'm stuck with a script that's already running and needs to be killed. How may I go about finding and killing this script?

Comment: Well, for this one-time case, just create the dummy file that it's waiting for. Then look at how to make that unnecessary in the future.

Comment: I don't understand why ps -e wouldn't display the pid of the process. The fact that it's sleeping shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: @IoanAlexandruCucu: I don't understand it either.

Comment: So what makes you think the script is still running? Isn't there a chance that it might have crashed?

Comment: @IoanAlexandruCucu: check out the code, it logs to a file

Comment: Are the logs still being written to? If yes, you could probably do a lsof on the log files and see what process continues to write them. But I honestly doubt your script is still running...

Comment: @IoanAlexandruCucu: I just found it. The script /is/ still running. The reason it didn't show up on `ps aux | grep python` is because osx likes things to be capitalized; my process showed up when I did `ps aux | grep Python` (note the capitalization in `Python`)

Comment: Well, doing a 'lsof FuzzyLog' would have helped you discover this faster. Anyways, funny story :)

Comment: Thanks @IoanAlexandruCucu for reminding me about `lsof`. I should write it down for next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional way Unix daemons handle this problem is with "pid files".

When your program starts up (or when your launcher starts your program up), it creates a file in a well-known location (`/var/run/<PROGRAM NAME>.pid` for system daemons; per-user daemons don't have a universal equivalent), writes the PID into that file (as in the ASCII string `12345\n` for PID 12345), and deletes it when it exits. So, you can just `kill $(cat /var/run/myprogram.pid)`.

However, it doesn't seem like you need this here. You could easily design the program to be cleanly shutdown, instead of designing it to be killable.

Or, even easier, remove the sleep; instead of having cron run your script it every hour and having the script sleep for a minute at a time until the PDF file is created, just have LaunchServices run the script when the PDF is created.

Comment: I just looked it up and get how LauchServices can be used (in theory). But seeing as I've never come close to working with it before, is there a simpler solution (I'm working on creating the file for this one time)? Alternatively, would you be able to point me in the right direction, so I could start my first experiment with LaunchServices?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: [Creating Launch Daemons and Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) is the best place I know of to start. It has some sample launchd plist files (like cron schedules, but more flexible and a lot more verbose) for different use cases, like running your program every time a file gets added to a specific directory.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Also, if the reference docs linked from that guide are still incomplete (I haven't really looked since 10.4 or 10.5 or so), `man launchd.plist` should have all the details.

Comment: Thank you. I am looking this up right now and will let you know if I run into more trouble

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: I'm sure you'll enjoy writing simple shell command lines in XML as much as everyone else does. :) But the ability to run stuff of all kinds of fancy triggers instead of just a timer means it's often worth it.